# Reference request: infinite-dimensional manifolds

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, locally-convex-spaces, global-analysis

The following books and/or notes develop various aspects of the theory of infinite-dimensional manifolds:

1. Lang, *Fundamentals of Differential Geometry*.
2. Kriegl & Michor, *The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis*.
3. Choquet-Bruhat & DeWitt-Morette, *Analysis, Manifolds and Physics*.
4. Klingenberg, *Riemannian Geometry*.
5. Marsden, Ratiu, and Abraham, *Manifolds, Tensor Analysis, and Applications*.
6. Hamilton, *The inverse function theorem of Nash and Moser*.

**Question**: *Are there any other books that systematically develop from scratch the theory of infinite-dimensional manifolds, in particular Frechet manifolds*?

Answer (score 1):

It's not specifically a text on infinite-dimensional manifolds, but the theory of diffeology developed in [Patrick Iglesias-Zemmour's text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821891316) encompasses infinite dimensional manifolds of all sorts (Banach, Frechet, etc.). The category of diffeological spaces is also a quasi-topos, which is a really fantastic property.

Answer (score 0):

[*Infinite-Dimensional Lie Groups*](https://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00391789/document) by Karl-Hermann Neeb looks really nice. It includes basics of the theory of infinite-dimensional manifolds in chapter 2. He also shows how the theory of linear ODEs collapses for Frechet spaces.